# Minimal C compiler for Windows 10

Tags: software-development

I looked at gcc but it seemed to require a lot of overhead. I already have Microsoft Visual C++ installed but I would like easy to use command-line compiler.

Can you recommend anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of overhead"?

Comment: The mingw + gcc downloads are a total of < 100 MB compared to VisStudio 2017 about 20 GB that doesn't seem like a lot of overhead.

Comment: @RichardChambers I means that I had to install more than just a C compiler. At the end I managed with MinGW + CLion and it worked.

Comment: For pretty much any situation, you're going to get more than _just_ a C compiler, because nobody needs only the compiler  (you at minimum also need the runtime libraries, an assembler, a linker, and probably a shared object archive tool (`ar` in UNIX terms)).